# how to open Text File in Google Colab

Tags: jupyter-notebook, python-3.5, google-colaboratory

I am recently been using google collab juypter notebook. After Uploading the text file, unable to open the file using an open function in Python 3.

```
from google.colab import files
import io

uploaded = files.upload()

for fn in uploaded.keys():
  print('User uploaded file "{name}" with length {length} bytes'.format(
      name=fn, length=len(uploaded[fn])))
data_path = io.StringIO(uploaded['fra.txt'].decode('utf-8'))
with open(data_path, 'rb') as f:
    lines = f.read().split('\n')
```

but it gives this error : TypeError: expected str, bytes, or os.PathLike object, not _io.StringIO

how to open a text file in google colab juypter notebook?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change to just

```
data_path = 'fra.txt'
```

Should work.

Comment: Worked.  But watch out for the read bytes data type ('rb'); might want to use 'r' to bring in str data type.  See example here... https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1hIwdk32cu2WeFGMWwMbtKj002l4m8XHV

Answer (score 0):

The _io.StringIO refers to the StringIO object (in-memory file stream).  "For strings StringIO can be used like a file opened in text mode."

The issue is that the file is already open and you have it available to you as a StringIO buffer.  I think you want to do readlines() on the StringIO object (data_path).

You can also call getvalue() on the object and get the str of the entire buffer.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO

See my example here; which I started with your code...

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Vbh13FVm02HMXeHXx-Zko1pFpqyp7bwI

Answer (score -1):

do like this

```py
with open('anna.txt', 'r') as f:    
   text=f.read()
vocab = sorted(set(text)) 
vocab_to_int = {c: i for i, c in enumerate(vocab)}    
int_to_vocab = dict(enumerate(vocab))    
encoded = np.array([vocab_to_int[c] for c in text], dtype=np.int32)
```